# VEditor (Verilog Editor for Eclipse) in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed VEditor (http://sourceforge.net/projects/veditor/) in Eclipse, apparently successfully. But I can't seem to use it!

I'm new to Eclipse plugins (and to Eclipse itself, as a matter of fact), but I'm guessing I would have the option to create a new project with the type "Verilog Project", or something, but there's no such thing.

Also, I tried importing my current "project" (no .eclipse file, it's just a lot of files in some folders) into eclipse and opening one of the files, and the syntax highlighting doesn't work.

So, I'm looking for a path: **what do I have to do to code my Verilog projects in Eclipse with VEditor (or any other plugin that serves the same purpose)**

Comment: Eclipse Galileo (3.5 you are correct) may prove to be a bit *too* recent for that plugin to run properly. Hence my suggestion to: 1/ not touch anything to your *current* eclipse installation; 2/ make a custom installation elsewhere with an older eclipse and the right JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [verilog plugin](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/veditor/index.php?title=Main_Page) is tested on Eclipse 3.2.1, on what version of eclipse do you have those issues?

As recommended in the [HowTo page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/veditor/index.php?title=HowTo), you can try to have a fresh eclipse3.2/JDK5 installation (beside your current eclipse installation) in order to manage your VHDL projects in that instance.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Galileo (3.5 I guess). So, bottom line is, it probably doesn't work in this version?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind spending money to get a *working* IDE: [use amiq's DVTEclipse](https://www.dvteclipse.com/).
afaik, you get the whole package: Verilog, SystemVerilog, VHDL, ***e***.

[image]
<sub>(source: [dvteclipse.com](https://www.dvteclipse.com/img/shutter/dvt_app_full.png))</sub>